# Get raw MIME for an Outlook Message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, eml, microsoft-graph-mail

I was able to get the mail object with attachment using following API Call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/${messageId}?$expand=attachments
```

[image]

I need to save raw MIME for the mail (i.e. `.eml`) which will be uploaded to our internal CRM.

I understand that one can make a simple `.eml` file in below fashion but I want to know if there is a simpler alternative to get this from the API directly.

```
To: Demo-Recipient <demo@demo.example.com>
Subject: EML with attachments
X-Unsent: 0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--boundary_text_string

----boundary_text_string
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<html>
<body>
<p>Example</p>
</body>
</html>

----boundary_text_string
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=demo.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment
ZXhhbXBsZQ==

----boundary_text_string
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=demo.log
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment
ZXhhbXBsZQ==

----boundary_text_string--
```

Comment: I've updated your question. What you're actually describing is the raw MIME text for the message. This isn't available in Graph yet but you can an early preview at `/beta/me/messages/{id}/$value`. Note that this is neither supported nor fully documented so _please don't use this in production_.

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur , what alternative would you suggest me if i were to do it in production environment. Should i be looking into the other Outlook API ?

Comment: The Outlook REST API is effectively the same as Graph (they're the same API behind the scenes). The best option at the moment is most likely constructing the MIME version on your end.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways one can get a message in raw format (MIME), and both are now available in v1.0 of the Microsoft Graph API:

1. Append a $value to a [get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) operation.
2. If a message is attached as a file or item to another Outlook item (message or event) or group post, you can get that message attachment by appending $value to the [get attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#get-the-raw-contents-of-a-file-or-item-attachment) operation.

[Get MIME content of a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message) describes the two scenarios.

In general, keeping an eye on the [Microsoft Graph blog site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/mime-format-support-for-outlook-mail-and-attachments-translate-item-id-apis-are-now-available-in-microsoft-graph-v1-0/), the [what's new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/whats-new-earlier#september-2019-new-and-generally-available) topic, or the [changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog#september-2019) topic (if it's API or permissions updates) would help you discover additions and updates you were looking for. In particular, the ability to get the MIME format of a message or message type attachment was introduced in April 2019 in the beta version, and promoted to v1.0 in September a few months later.